# Firing up CustomUnboundColumnData again

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

Hello how am I able to fire up `CustomUnboundColumnData` again when a cell has been changed or when the quantity of the product became 0? I am working on a `repositoryItemPictureEdit` to show picture of the product and when it is out of stock it should show in grayscale. So far what I have done is creating the event but it will only work once after the form is loaded.

```
private void layoutView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Image" && e.IsGetData)
    {
        var colorName = (string)((DataRowView)e.Row)["mnupicture"];
        var qty = (int)((DataRowView)e.Row)["mnuqty"];
        var fileName = GetFileName(colorName).ToLower();
        if (!Images.ContainsKey(fileName))
        {
            var img = (Image)null;
            try
            {
                var filePath = FilesHelper.FindingFileName(Application.StartupPath, fileName, false);
                img = Image.FromFile(filePath);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
            if (qty <= 0)
            {
                img = ConvertToGrayscale(new Bitmap(img));
                Images.Add(fileName, img);
            }
            else
                Images.Add(fileName, img);
        }
        e.Value = Images[fileName];
    }
}
```

The quantity depends on the changes in my database. This makes me periodically sets DataSource to get a new data from the database.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal I suggest you refresh the required cell via the [GridView.RefreshRowCell](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RefreshRowCelltopic) or via the [ColumnView.RefreshRow](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_RefreshRowtopic) method when it needed (when value in the column from which the image-column depends has changed).